# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted, on decryption

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, stream, padding

I know this error has been subject of many post on this forum, but most of the time the issue of those post is charset ecoding beauxe people want to cipher strings. 
The issue is that in my case i'm trying to cipher a 2d string array and pass it from a server to a client. To do so i'm using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which I'm passing to a `ObjectOutputStream` to convert this 2d array into byte, and same concept on client side whit input stream to convert it back from byte to 2d String array.

The convertion from string array to byte array is ok, but I have a  `pad block corrupted` exception when I'm trying to decrypt my byte array with `doFinal()` on client size.

Here is the server code:

```
case GET_NEXT_BILL:
{
    int lastGetId= (int)params.get(0);
    // recup params
    cs.TraceEvenements(adresseDistante+"#Get facture#"+Thread.currentThread().getName());

    System.out.println("Recuperation de la cle secrète");
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) servKs.getEntry("clesecComptChiffr", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("pass".toCharArray()));
    SecretKey cléSecrète = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

    Cipher chiffr = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
    chiffr.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cléSecrète);

    ResultSet rs = bdAccess.select("SELECT IDFacture, Montant, Destinataire, AdresseLivraison, DATE_FORMAT(DateEmission, '%d-%m-%Y') as DateEmission"
                     + " FROM FACTURES WHERE IDFacture > "+lastGetId+" AND Valide= 0");

    if(rs.next())
    {
        String[][] stringArray = {{String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)), String.valueOf(rs.getFloat(2)), 
            rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5)}};

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(stringArray);

        rep.add(chiffr.doFinal(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
         typeRep= TypesRep.OK; 
    }
    else
    {
        rep.add("Il n'y a plus de facture non validée");
        typeRep= TypesRep.ERREUR; 
    }    
    break;
}
```

And the client code, where the exception is thrown:

```
    EnvoiRequete(cliSock, new RequeteBIMAP(TypesReq.GET_NEXT_BILL, params));
    ReponseP rep = (ReponseP)LectureReponse(cliSock);

    if(rep.getTypeRet() == Reponse.TypesRep.OK){
        try {
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) cliKs.getEntry("clesecComptChiffr", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("pass".toCharArray()));
            SecretKey cle = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();

            Cipher dechiffr = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
            dechiffr.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cle);

            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dechiffr.doFinal((byte[])rep.getParams().get(0)));

            String[][] stringArray2= null;
             try (ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
                stringArray2 = (String[][]) objectInputStream.readObject();
             }

            ListeFactures lf= new ListeFactures(stringArray2);
            lf.setVisible(true);

            lastGetID= Integer.valueOf(stringArray2[0][0]);
            FieldFacture.setText(stringArray2[0][0]);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchPaddingException | IOException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnrecoverableEntryException | KeyStoreException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Comptable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rep.getParams().get(0));
```

Comment: Typically a padding error is really a decryption failure. Ensure the exact same modes, padding, key and IV are being used for encryption and decryption, use hex dumps to verify. Try to get things working with very simple short data and then work up to your final data needs.  Also using ECB mode, that is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: Are you sure you've transmitted the ciphertext completely? And without extra junk?

Comment: Yes, I think the issue is comming from my session key exchange